# How to if ... else in mod_rewrite htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem configuring the .htaccess file

`<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '127.0.0.1'"> RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpg|png))$ https://cdn.amante.co.kr/$1 [R=301,L,NC] </If>`

Eror:
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
  <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} == '127.0.0.1'">
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpg|png))$ https://cdn.amante.co.kr/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</If>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^asset.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12.345\.678\.901$


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`

Comment: No real need to wrap this into an if condition, you can check on the content of `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` using a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following code for your .htaccess:
Rewrite Engine On

```
# If the file or directory does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Check for "address1" or "address2" in URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} address1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} address2
```

## If one of the conditions is true, redirect to newaddress.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newaddress.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
Thus, if "address1" or "address2" is present in the URI, and if the requested path is not an existing file or directory, the request will be redirected to newaddress.php, receiving the path as a variable